# Cannot get the value of field Realm

Tags: java, android, android-studio, realm

I am working with Realm, basicly is a simple app where i need to add a movie and a category, i have 2 diferent models for this(Category and Movie), but my problem is just related to the category at the moment.

**Model Category:**

```
package com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.ex4realm.model;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

/**
 * Created by FilipeCosta on 18/05/2017.
 */

public class Categoria extends RealmObject {
    private String nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Categoria(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Categoria() {
    }
}
```

basicly i add a realm object(that part is working fine) then i want to construct a spinner that should have all categories(the name of them).

**So i did this:**

```
public class List extends AppCompatActivity {

    Realm realm;
    Spinner spinner;

    ArrayAdapter<Categoria> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        RealmQuery<Categoria> query = realm.where(Categoria.class);



        if(realm.isEmpty()){
            Log.d("empty","empty");
        }

        RealmResults<Categoria> result1 = query.findAll();
        Log.d("result",String.valueOf(result1));

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Categoria>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result1);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

the issue is that i get this on the spinner: Categoria[{nome:Futebol}]

i just want to get this: Futebol(and of course the same to the other instances inside the spinner.

any tip?

Thanks

Comment: Try deleting an element from Realm, then click the elements in your list (or scroll up/down), then read the docs and use `RealmBaseAdapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the `toString` method to `Categoria` to make it work.

just add this method to class `Categoria`:

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
```

Comment: i should have remind that, thank you a lot, just one question, what if my model had more then 1 atribute and i need to get for example the name and the age(user for example)

Comment: they you need to make a loop and create a `List` of strings yourself.

Comment: Disagree with list of strings in context of Realm unless you truly have no other option.

Comment: then what better approach can you suggest?

Comment: subclassing `RealmBaseAdapter` from https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters